# Is there a way to stop people from entering another language into an online form?

Tags: arrays, database, forms, ascii, cjk

For example, some people might enter Chinese or Japanese characters into our forms. But we only want them to input English into the fields because it would make them much easier to read in our database (because I can't read it).

One of the workarounds I thought of is to feed the information into a Google Translate API and return English after the person submits, but since some fields like "name" would be very hard to translate, I don't think this is a viable solution. Perhaps it might work if we limit form input to only ASCII latin characters? I'm not sure if that works, because sometimes the forms use 3rd party software like Google or Microsoft forms (out of my control).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!